# How does pandas / numpy round() work when decimal>=1?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, rounding

I have a pandas series

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: s = pd.Series([1.3, 2.6, 1.24, 1.27, 1.45])
```

and I need to round the numbers.

```
In [4]: s.round(1)
Out[4]:
0    1.3
1    2.6
2    1.2
3    1.3
4    1.4
dtype: float64
```

it works for `1.27`, however `1.45` is rounded to be `1.4`, is it the problem of the precision loss of float type? If it is, how can I deal with this problem?

Comment: It rounding half to even by convention: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This isn't a bug but it is because, most decimal numbers cannot be represented exactly as a float.

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/round

another way of rounding is:

```
int(number*10^precission+0.5)
```

however, you might run in simular problems because who knows if 1.45 is closer to 1.4499999.. or 1.4500...1

Answer (score 0):

In general, `round()` often fails due to floats being imprecise estimates.

In this case though, it's because of a convention by which half of all the numbers (evens) are rounded down, in order to balance out rounding error.

[You can pretty easily disable this behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex):

> round(x[, n])
>   x rounded to n digits, rounding half to even. If n is omitted, it defaults to 0.